# How can I figure out this question about install port using pip

Tags: python, pip

I want to install the package `port`.The OS is Mac OS 10.15.6. The terminal showed these error:

```
(base) bash-3.2$ pip install port
```

```
Collecting port
  Using cached port-1.1.4-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyrss2gen
  Using cached PyRSS2Gen-1.1-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from port) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from port) (5.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: watchdog==0.8.3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from port) (0.8.3)
Collecting nom
  Using cached nom-1.4.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting click==6.2
  Using cached click-6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (70 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: argh>=0.24.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from watchdog==0.8.3->port) (0.26.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pathtools>=0.1.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from watchdog==0.8.3->port) (0.1.2)
Collecting Jinja2==2.8
  Using cached Jinja2-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (263 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: Pygments==2.1.3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from nom->port) (2.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: Markdown==2.6.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from nom->port) (2.6.5)
Collecting html2text==2015.11.4
  Using cached html2text-2015.11.4-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting lxml==3.5.0
  Using cached lxml-3.5.0.tar.gz (3.8 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: websocket-server==0.4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from nom->port) (0.4)
Collecting gfm==0.0.3
  Using cached gfm-0.0.3-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: py-gfm==0.1.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from nom->port) (0.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Jinja2==2.8->nom->port) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from py-gfm==0.1.1->nom->port) (47.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: unittest2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from py-gfm==0.1.1->nom->port) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil->port) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: traceback2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from unittest2->py-gfm==0.1.1->nom->port) (1.4.0)
Collecting argparse
  Using cached argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: linecache2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from traceback2->unittest2->py-gfm==0.1.1->nom->port) (1.0.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: lxml
  Building wheel for lxml (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/2m/5c6f3dp53939057p3xz0ys1c0000gn/T/pip-install-2bbhvpwz/lxml_3ae795971a7a4a38adceb54ead864a4e/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/2m/5c6f3dp53939057p3xz0ys1c0000gn/T/pip-install-2bbhvpwz/lxml_3ae795971a7a4a38adceb54ead864a4e/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/2m/5c6f3dp53939057p3xz0ys1c0000gn/T/pip-wheel-if_aavgp
       cwd: /private/var/folders/2m/5c6f3dp53939057p3xz0ys1c0000gn/T/pip-install-2bbhvpwz/lxml_3ae795971a7a4a38adceb54ead864a4e/
  Complete output (85 lines):
  Building lxml version 3.5.0.
  Building without Cython.
  Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.29
  Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml
  copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml
  copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml
  copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml
  copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml
  copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml
  copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml
  copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml
  copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml
  copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron
  copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml
  copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml
  copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  running build_ext
  building 'lxml.etree' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src/lxml
  /usr/local/bin/gcc-9 -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w -flat_namespace
  unable to execute '/usr/local/bin/gcc-9': No such file or directory
  Compile failed: command '/usr/local/bin/gcc-9' failed with exit status 1
  creating var
  creating var/folders
  creating var/folders/2m
  creating var/folders/2m/5c6f3dp53939057p3xz0ys1c0000gn
  creating var/folders/2m/5c6f3dp53939057p3xz0ys1c0000gn/T
  cc -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /var/folders/2m/5c6f3dp53939057p3xz0ys1c0000gn/T/xmlXPathInitze9cdjlm.c -o var/folders/2m/5c6f3dp53939057p3xz0ys1c0000gn/T/xmlXPathInitze9cdjlm.o
  cc var/folders/2m/5c6f3dp53939057p3xz0ys1c0000gn/T/xmlXPathInitze9cdjlm.o -L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib -lxml2 -o a.out
  error: command '/usr/local/bin/gcc-9' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lxml
  Running setup.py clean for lxml
Failed to build lxml
Installing collected packages: argparse, lxml, Jinja2, html2text, gfm, click, pyrss2gen, nom, port
  Attempting uninstall: lxml
    Found existing installation: lxml 4.6.2
    Uninstalling lxml-4.6.2:
      Successfully uninstalled lxml-4.6.2
    Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/2m/5c6f3dp53939057p3xz0ys1c0000gn/T/pip-install-2bbhvpwz/lxml_3ae795971a7a4a38adceb54ead864a4e/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/2m/5c6f3dp53939057p3xz0ys1c0000gn/T/pip-install-2bbhvpwz/lxml_3ae795971a7a4a38adceb54ead864a4e/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/2m/5c6f3dp53939057p3xz0ys1c0000gn/T/pip-record-ol8yht6w/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/lxml
         cwd: /private/var/folders/2m/5c6f3dp53939057p3xz0ys1c0000gn/T/pip-install-2bbhvpwz/lxml_3ae795971a7a4a38adceb54ead864a4e/
    Complete output (80 lines):
    Building lxml version 3.5.0.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.29
    Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml
    copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml
    copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml
    copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml
    copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml
    copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml
    copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml
    copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml
    copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml
    copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/html
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron
    copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml
    copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml
    copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    running build_ext
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src/lxml
    /usr/local/bin/gcc-9 -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w -flat_namespace
    unable to execute '/usr/local/bin/gcc-9': No such file or directory
    Compile failed: command '/usr/local/bin/gcc-9' failed with exit status 1
    cc -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /var/folders/2m/5c6f3dp53939057p3xz0ys1c0000gn/T/xmlXPathInitpxou4we_.c -o var/folders/2m/5c6f3dp53939057p3xz0ys1c0000gn/T/xmlXPathInitpxou4we_.o
    cc var/folders/2m/5c6f3dp53939057p3xz0ys1c0000gn/T/xmlXPathInitpxou4we_.o -L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib -lxml2 -o a.out
    error: command '/usr/local/bin/gcc-9' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of lxml
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lxml-4.6.2.dist-info/
   from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/~xml-4.6.2.dist-info
  Moving to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lxml/
   from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/~xml
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/2m/5c6f3dp53939057p3xz0ys1c0000gn/T/pip-install-2bbhvpwz/lxml_3ae795971a7a4a38adceb54ead864a4e/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/2m/5c6f3dp53939057p3xz0ys1c0000gn/T/pip-install-2bbhvpwz/lxml_3ae795971a7a4a38adceb54ead864a4e/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/2m/5c6f3dp53939057p3xz0ys1c0000gn/T/pip-record-ol8yht6w/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/lxml Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Try running in su

Comment: Run `which gcc-9` in a shell. Does it produce any output?

Comment: @Xua Sorry I don't know what su is.

Comment: @MichaelRuth No any output

Comment: @YuLiming, then gcc-9 is not installed on your system but pip is trying to use it to compile src/lxml/lxml.etree.c. I'm a little surprised that a mac would use gcc as opposed to clang, but that's a different issue. Installing gcc-9 could fix the error. Otherwise, look into why your mac isn't using the C compiler that it already has.